# Adding document link in pdf by Migradoc

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp, migradoc

I use PdfSharp/Migradoc to generate PDF file in c#, now i tried to add document link inside the pdf file, basically it's to create a table of items, and click the item name to navigate to another detail page. I tried to use the Migradoc `Paragraph.AddHyperlink()` method, below it's the code used

```
Paragraph p = cell.AddParagraph();

Hyperlink link = p.AddHyperlink(tmp_value, HyperlinkType.Bookmark);
link.AddText(tmp_value);
link.AddPageRefField(some_bookmark);
```

My issue is this navigation page is created before the bookmarks are generated later on, after execution, the link is not appeared and only error message like "[item name] the bookmark [some_bookmark] is not defined", anyone can highlight me what's the proper way to acheve this? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like `paragraph.AddBookmark(tmp_value);` as the target of the jump. That's what the error message is telling you: target bookmark not defined.

MigraDoc creates the PDF in two passes and it does not matter where in the document the target is.

`link.AddPageRefField(some_bookmark);` will add the page number of the page with the bookmark "some_bookmark". What's the purpose of that?

See also:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx

```
Hyperlink hyperlink = paragraph.AddHyperlink("Paragraphs"); 
hyperlink.AddText("Paragraphs\t"); 
hyperlink.AddPageRefField("Paragraphs");
```

The first line defines the target - the string defined with `AddBookmark` elsewhere in the document.
The second line gives text that is shown in the link. The third line adds a page number to the link.

Comment: Thanks for the explain, so the target and refer page should point to the same bookmark, my next question is, does the bookmark used in the hyperlink must be defined before creating the link?

Comment: The target must exist when the PDF is being rendered. When you create the link, MigraDoc just stores the string that you pass without any checks. You do not have to create the target before you add the link (the linked MigraDoc sample also does it in this order).

Comment: Hi @ThomasH, I realize where my issue from, I create a table using MigraDoc and it cross multiple pages, on each page I did a RenderPage(), otherwise it will show blank in the final pdf (I don't know why), so that's the issue, during the rendering, it can't find the bookmarks used in the link definition, as my bookmarks will only defined in the later pages, can you give me some idea on solving this issue? thanks.

Comment: Create the document using RenderDocument. See this sample: http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocHelloWorld-sample.ashx If you think your code should work, but there is a bug in MigraDoc, please provide an SSCCE (http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=832).